# Sorting nested dictionaries at two levels from TOML configuration

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have the idea to create a TOML configuration file which defines some sort of job chain to be executed. Those jobs are not executed immediate, there may be a break in between, so there should also be some grouping to have the chance to do something in between the chain.

An example TOML file looks like this:

```ini
[jobid_3.2]
name='script_3.2'
type='sql'
[jobid_10.1]
name='whatever_works'
type='shell'
[jobid_1.1]
name='script_1.1'
type='shell'
[jobid_3.1]
name='foobar'
type='shell'
[jobid_2.1]
name='barbaz'
type='shell'
[jobid_2.2]
name='script_2.2'
type='sql'
```

So, the order is a bit messy, therefore the configuration read should then be in some ordered state.

Problem 1: when reading the TOML string in to a variable, you end up with nested dictionaries, in this case 3 (jobid_xxx, y, and then a dict with name type)
Problem 2: TOML recognizes an integer as string, not as an integer if used as arrays of tables. That means we have to do some conversion in the first nested dictionary.
Problem 3: sorting on the first level should happen on the digit, not on the string itself. Of course, I could use `[3.2]` instead of `[jobid_3.2]`, but this actually looks a bit nicer and descriptive.

So, how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

It took me some time how this may work, with a lot of trials and fails. However, the working solution looks like this:

```py
import tomli
from collections import OrderedDict

string = """[jobid_3.2]
name='script_3.2'
type='sql'
[jobid_10.1]
name='whatever_works'
type='shell'
[jobid_1.1]
name='script_1.1'
type='shell'
[jobid_3.1]
name='foobar'
type='shell'
[jobid_2.1]
name='barbaz'
type='shell'
[jobid_2.2]
name='script_2.2'
type='sql'
"""

t = tomli.loads(string)

scripts = OrderedDict(
    sorted(
        {
            k_outer: dict(
                sorted(
                    {
                        int(k_inner): v_inner for k_inner, v_inner in v_outer.items()
                    }.items()
                )
            )
            for k_outer, v_outer in t.items()
        }.items(),
        key=lambda x: int(re.match("^.+_(\d+)", x[0]).group(1)),
    )
)

print(scripts)
```

The output:

```
OrderedDict([('jobid_1', {1: {'name': 'script_1.1', 'type': 'shell'}}),
             ('jobid_2',
              {1: {'name': 'barbaz', 'type': 'shell'},
               2: {'name': 'script_2.2', 'type': 'sql'}}),
             ('jobid_3',
              {1: {'name': 'foobar', 'type': 'shell'},
               2: {'name': 'script_3.2', 'type': 'sql'}}),
             ('jobid_10', {1: {'name': 'whatever_works', 'type': 'shell'}})])
```

It really looks comlicated, it took me half a day to figure this out, but it works great.

The most inner sort is for dictionaries on level 2, where we also want to convert the digit string into an ordinary integer. Therefore we have to take the values from the parent dictionary (v_outer). The outer `sorted` is to finally do the sort overall on level one. We use a regex and convert the match into an integer, so that we get 1,2,3,4,..., 10 and not 1,10,2,3,4,...

As an alternative you could use `[3.2]` as table marker and leave out the trailing string `jobid_`, therefore you might want to change the code a bit:

```py
scripts = OrderedDict(
    sorted(
        {
            int(k_outer): dict(
                sorted(
                    {int(k_inner): v_inner for k_inner, v_inner in v_outer.items()}.items()
                )
            ) for k_outer, v_outer in t.items()
        }.items()
    )
)
```

You can drop the key in the outer `sorted`, but you need to convert the string into an integer.

If there's maybe an easier way out there, please share this here, I'd be very interested!